# Why does a function declaration within another function compile and what does it do?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I intended to call a private class member function, but by a copy&paste mistake pasted the line as this function is declared in the header file:

```
void DebugView::on_cbYAxisEnabled_stateChanged(int)
{
    void updateAxisEnabled();
}
```

instead of

```
void DebugView::on_cbYAxisEnabled_stateChanged(int)
{
    updateAxisEnabled();
}
```

Surprisingly, the code was compiled and executed. However the method `updateAxisEnabled()` was not executed.

So, why does it compile? Was here a local function declared within a method body or has `void` instructed the compiler to ignore whatever comes afterwards?

The compiler is Visual Studio 2008.

P.S.: I'm aware of class declaration/definition within functions, but not functions within functions in C++.

Comment: `P.S.: I'm aware of class declaration/definition within functions, but not functions within functions in C++` Well, now you know that's possible too.

Comment: @deviantfan: I'm sure, that it is not legal to DEFINE a local function in C++. So what is the point to DELCARE a local function without being able to define a body for it?

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz Have you tried with g++ for example,I am curious how that would work.

Comment: The same reason you forward declare anything; telling the compiler that a symbol's definition exists elsewhere.

Comment: @RichardRublev: yes, seems to work, Tried here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/

Comment: @AndyG: Ok, got it! The scope is global, so there is no magic here actually.

Comment: I think this a variant of the classic "vexing parse" issue. See e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)

Comment: @user786653: I don't think, the issues are related. The issue you meant, is focused on "()" is not an expression in C++. Here I was not aware, that forward declaration is possible within a member function. It is clear, that whatever looks like function declaration in C++ will be taken by the compiler as function. A a(); in the case of the question you mentioned is obviously a function declaration, not the object creation of class A.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz: Of course it is related, if local function declarations were not allowed, the most vexing parse would cease to be ambiguous.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`void updateAxisEnabled();` is a function *declaration*.

Sample:

```
#include <cstdio>

void a();
void b();

int main(void) {
    a();
    b();
    return 0;
}

void a() {
    void c(); // Declaration
    c(); // Call it
}

void b() {
    c(); // Error: not declared
}

void c() {
    puts("Hello, world!");
}
```

Comment: Cool! It works. I've tried it here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/. Good to know, that it's possible to make forward declaration in a member function. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It is perfectly allowed to declare a function inside a function scope: a function may be declared in any scope.

A common mistake among C++ programmers is indeed to:

```
void foo()
{
    MyObject bar(); // 1
    bar.someMethod(); // 2
}
```

this will miserably fail to compile because line 1 is *not* declaring a `MyObject` named `bar` and calling its constructor explicitly; rather, it is declaring a *function* named `bar` that returns a `MyObject`. Thefore, there is really no object to call `someMethod` on.

Comment: This is why I like using this syntax to initialize my variables: `MyObject bar{};`

Comment: @Just Yes, the uniform initialization can solve this usses since C++11.

Comment: Note, however, that you can't declare a non-member function at class scope, unless you make it a friend.

Comment: @Brian: what is the syntax fo it?

Comment: @Brian Weird! One can even define a global not-member function inside class declaration scope. Seems to be  another case for: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/unmain.html :-)

Comment: @Brian Right, member functions are an exception.